# About Spring BeanFactory

Tags: spring

Does every time I new an new BeanFactory the beans in the XML file are to be recreated? In other words, if I set an bean's scope to Singleton, I got the same Object even if I newed another BeanFactory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: yes, for one `BeanFactory`, no, for creating a `BeanFactory` each time.

---

If you use `scope="singleton"`, which is the default setting, you will get the same instance each time from *the same* `BeanFactory`.

Spring does not manage scope across multiple, unrelated, *BeanFactory* instances.

Why you would create multiple bean factories?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: **no**

you can try it yourself by creating two BeanFactory, then two times the same bean and then:

```
assert bean1 == bean2;
```

or

```
assert bean1.equals(bean2);
```